# How to print to output (not stdout) in Linux (GCC)?

Tags: c++, linux

On Windows there is [OutputDebugString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, how do I do the same on Linux?

Update: stderr and stdlog is not what I want. Those are redirected to stdout.
P. S. And `syslog` is no different.

Comment: Which window manager are you using? And is this a console or winodwed application?

Comment: @johnathon: it's a console app, and I wouldn't like to rely on a certain WM.

Comment: std::cerr does not necessarily redirect to stdout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qDebug` on Linux is redirected to stdout. There is no way to get two distinct output streams as with `OutputDebugString` on Windows. There appears to be no dedicated debug output stream on Linux.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure what `OutputDebugString` does exactly, but standard C++ defines the standard error stream `std::cerr` and the standard logging stream `std::clog`. Both are declared in the header `<iostream>`.

These are by default tied to the same file descriptor in Linux; the difference is that `cerr` is unbuffered, while `clog` is buffered (I believe it's line-buffered).

There is no notion of a "system debugger" in Linux. If you want to write to the system log, you can use `syslog(3)`.

Comment: Thank you. By the way, what does 3 mean is `syslog(3)`? I see such a notation often, but can't understand the meaning.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: it means `syslog` is in section 3 of the Linux manual. `man 3 syslog` will bring up the manpage for it.

Comment: Those are all displayed in the console instead of "output" window in the IDE. Any further ideas?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: check your IDE documentation. I don't use IDEs, so I can't help you further.

Answer (score 5):

There is probably no exact equivalent of such a function in Linux or Posix systems.

You could output to `stderr` (if in C or C++), or to `std::cerr` or `std::clog` in C++.

Notice that with most shells, you can start some program and [redirect](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) differently and independently their stdout & their stderr.

For system logging, you could use the [openlog](http://linux.die.net/man/3/openlog) & `syslog` functions.

If you want to output to the controlling terminal (if it exists), you could use the [/dev/tty](http://linux.die.net/man/4/tty) device.